# What is the correct configuration for increasing the thrift frame size in Titan-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: cassandra, titan, tinkerpop3

I execute the count method on a cluster with a titan graph using the fulgora graph computer and get this common error:

`Frame size (20769719) larger than max length (15728640)!`

This can be corrected by specifying this in the config file:

`storage.cassandra.frame-size-mb=60`

However, when using the SparkGraphComputer on a hadoop graph pointing to the same data I get the same error. I have tried all of these settings and none of them work:

`titanmr.ioformat.conf.storage.cassandra.frame-size-mb=60`
`titanmr.ioformat.conf.storage.cassandra.frame-size=60`
`titan.hadoop.input.conf.storage.cassandra.thrift.frame-size=60`
`titan.hadoop.input.conf.storage.cassandra.thrift.frame-size-mb=60`
`storage.cassandra.thrift.frame-size=60`
`storage.cassandra.thrift.frame-size-mb=60`

Does anyone know the current correct setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cassandra read path is different when you're doing OLAP, so that's why using the Titan setting `storage.cassandra.frame-size-mb` doesn't work. Try this Cassandra setting: `cassandra.thrift.framed.size_mb`. It defaults to 15 MB.

References:

- [ConfigHelper.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1.9/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/hadoop/ConfigHelper.java#L498)
- [TFramedTransportFactory.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1.9/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/thrift/TFramedTransportFactory.java#L34-L35)